# Why can I fetch data in local environment but not in production (Heroku)?

Tags: node.js, heroku, axios, fetch, cheerio

I have a little Node application that is supposed to fetch data from a website and notify me when a new article is posted. The fetching part looks something like this

```
console.log("Fetching...");

const url = "https://www.jw.org/ro/ce-e-nou/";
const response = await axios(url, {
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));

console.log("Fetching done");
```

If i run my code locally everything works just fine. But if I deploy it as a worker on Heroku (because I can't do what I want to with a Express server) it shows "Fetching..." for a long time and after some minutes I get this massive timeout error

```
AxiosError: read ETIMEDOUT
   at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
 syscall: 'read',
 code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
 errno: -110,
 config: {
   transitional: {
     silentJSONParsing: true,
     forcedJSONParsing: true,
     clarifyTimeoutError: false
   },
   adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
   transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
   transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
   timeout: 0,
   xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
   xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
   maxContentLength: -1,
   maxBodyLength: -1,
   env: { FormData: [Function] },
   validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
   headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
     'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
   },
   url: 'https://www.jw.org/ro/ce-e-nou/',
   method: 'get',
   data: undefined
 },
 request: <ref *1> Writable {
   _writableState: WritableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     finalCalled: false,
     needDrain: false,
     ending: false,
     ended: false,
     finished: false,
     destroyed: false,
     decodeStrings: true,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     length: 0,
     writing: false,
     corked: 0,
     sync: true,
     bufferProcessing: false,
     onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
     writecb: null,
     writelen: 0,
     afterWriteTickInfo: null,
     buffered: [],
     bufferedIndex: 0,
     allBuffers: true,
     allNoop: true,
     pendingcb: 0,
     constructed: true,
     prefinished: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     emitClose: true,
     autoDestroy: true,
     errored: null,
     closed: false,
     closeEmitted: false,
     [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
   },
   _events: [Object: null prototype] {
     response: [Function: handleResponse],
     error: [Function: handleRequestError],
     socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
   },
   _eventsCount: 3,
   _maxListeners: undefined,
   _options: {
     maxRedirects: 21,
     maxBodyLength: 10485760,
     protocol: 'https:',
     path: '/ro/ce-e-nou/',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: [Object],
     agent: undefined,
     agents: [Object],
     auth: undefined,
     hostname: 'www.jw.org',
     port: null,
     nativeProtocols: [Object],
     pathname: '/ro/ce-e-nou/'
   },
   _ended: true,
   _ending: true,
   _redirectCount: 0,
   _redirects: [],
   _requestBodyLength: 0,
   _requestBodyBuffers: [],
   _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
   _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
     _events: [Object: null prototype],
     _eventsCount: 7,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     outputData: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _last: true,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
     _defaultKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: 0,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     _closed: false,
     socket: [TLSSocket],
     _header: 'GET /ro/ce-e-nou/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
       'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n' +
       'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
       'Host: www.jw.org\r\n' +
       'Connection: close\r\n' +
       '\r\n',
     _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
     _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
     agent: [Agent],
     socketPath: undefined,
     method: 'GET',
     maxHeaderSize: undefined,
     insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
     path: '/ro/ce-e-nou/',
     _ended: false,
     res: null,
     aborted: false,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     reusedSocket: false,
     host: 'www.jw.org',
     protocol: 'https:',
     _redirectable: [Circular *1],
     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
     [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
     [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
     [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
   },
   _currentUrl: 'https://www.jw.org/ro/ce-e-nou/',
   [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
 }
```

What have I done wrong?